# gulp-useref does not work with gulp-merge

Tags: gulp, gulp-useref, gulp-merge

**Situation:** I have the following Gulp script, which should build all my html files to the distFolder. In addition it should build the external script files by parsing the links in index.html - this is what useref is good for.
I am not sure if this is the ideal way to go - but I need to split the html files - if I put in multiple html files I get write conflicts with cleanCSS() and uglify().

```
// Parse the html file and create external scripts
gulp.task('htmlscripts', function() {
    var s1 = gulp.src(['*.html', '!index.html'])
        .pipe(useref({noAssets: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    var s2 = gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(cache('useref'))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', cleanCSS()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder));
    return merge(s1, s2);
});

// Minify 
gulp.task('htmlmin', ['htmlscripts'], function() {
    return ...
});

gulp.task('default', ['htmlscripts', 'htmlmin']);
```

**Problem:** The 2nd task (htmlmin) is never loaded. It seems, that the 1st task (htmlscripts) does not return a valid end in the promise. (Dependency problem)

If I remove one of the two tasks the other one finishes correctly.

### I have done the following tests:

**Not working** (htmlmin task not started):

```
gulp.task('htmlscripts', function() {
    var s1 = gulp....
    var s2 = gulp....
    return merge(s1,s2);
});
```

**Working** (I mean at least the htmlmin script is run):

```
gulp.task('htmlscripts', function() {
    var s1 = gulp....
    var s2 = gulp....
    return merge(s1);
});
```

**Not working** (htmlmin task not started):

```
gulp.task('htmlscripts', function() {
    var s1 = gulp....
    var s2 = gulp....
    return merge(s2); // this one is really strange, isn't it? (see next test)
});
```

**Working** (I mean at least the htmlmin script is run):

```
gulp.task('htmlscripts', function() {
    // var s1 = gulp....
    var s2 = gulp....
    return merge(s2);
});
```

Comment: How come you have `htmlscripts` as a dependancy both for `htmlmin` and `default` tasks? Doesn't this pose a problem? A dependancy for `htmlmin` should be enough.

Comment: @lofihelsinki: you mean in the last line? This is my start task (when I run >gulp). I think it I have to list all my tasks here, don't I?

Comment: No, if `htmlscripts`is already a dependancy in `htmlmin`, it will be run every time `htmlmin`is run. Therefore you should remove it from the `default` task.

Comment: Ok, so when I use gulp, I only start the last task and the each task has the previous task as dependency? I have never read that... - I will try!

Comment: You could also leave the dependency out of `htmlmin` all together and just have both `htmlscripts` and `htmlmin` as dependencies for the `default` task. But no reason to have `htmlscripts` in two places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [`gulp-cached`](https://github.com/contra/gulp-cached)?

Could it be, that your resource in `s2` is found in the cache? Therefore `.pipe(cache('useref'))` won't pass the file forward and `s2` will be `null` ?

With `gulp-cached`, if a resource is found in the cache, it won't pass forward the cached resource. It passes nothing, i.e. it stops. Therefore `s2` will be empty.

I would try removing `.pipe(cache('useref'))` and see if it works?

Comment: I have removed gulp-cache as of your suggestions, but it didn't help. Some weeks and many reboots later I tried again and now it works without any problem. gulp-cache seems to be a dangerous tool ;-)